# Why Jest is sending me this timeout error?

Tags: node.js, async-await, jestjs, timeout, supertest

Actually this code don't work, the error message is :    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

I an blocked since 1 week can someone help me ? When i call the route /login on postman its works perfectly

```js
const session = require('express-session')
const res = require('express/lib/response')
const request = require('supertest')
const app = require("../routes/routes")

describe('test POST', () => {


    it('login', async () => {

        let result = await request(app)
        .post('/login')
        .send({
            loginID:"1705",
            loginPwd:"17051999"
        })

    
  
    
    })
 
})
```

I tried to increase the timeout but not works too

Here is the post route

```js
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    let id = req.body.loginID
    let mdp = req.body.loginPwd

    if (id != '' && id != undefined) {
        if (mdp != '' && mdp != undefined) {
            let Login = require('../models/M_Login')
            Login.testLogin(id,mdp, (result, id) => {
                console.log(result)
                switch (result.resultCode) {
                    case 0:
                        req.session.infoUser = result
                        req.session.infoUser.loginNo = id
                        req.session.success = 'Connexion réussie'
                        res.redirect('/accueil')
                        break
                    case 2001:
                        req.session.error = 'Identifiant inconnu'
                        res.redirect('/')
                        break
                    case 2002:
                        req.session.error = 'Mot de passe incorrect'
                        res.redirect('/')
                        break
                    case 1003:
                        req.session.error = 'Compte bloqué veuillez contacter l\'administrateur'
                        res.redirect('/')
                        break
                }
            })
        } else {
            req.session.error = 'Vous devez renseigner votre mot de passe'
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    } else {
        req.session.error = 'Vous devez renseigner votre identifiant'
        res.redirect('/')
    }


})
```

and here the function who call the API

```js
const axios = require('axios').default;
const { baseUrlServer } = require('../server')


class M_Login {

    static testLogin(id, mdp, cb) {

        axios.post(baseUrlServer + '/login/loginPwd', {
            "loginNo": id
            , "loginPwd": mdp
            , "domainNo": 0
        })
            .then(function (res) {
                cb(res.data, id)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                cb(error)
            })

    }

}

module.exports = M_Login
```

Comment: Without seeing everything, I believe you're missing the `callback()` on your app instance. `await request(app.callback()).post(...`

Comment: sesamechicken i changed the post i add all the code, what do you think ?

Comment: Are you exporting the main instance of app from here? `const app = require("../routes/routes")`

Comment: yes its de file which contains the login route

Comment: The route file above it not exporting the app itself - maybe if you post the complete code it might make more sense.

Comment: you need all the imports ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : I found the problem, it was on the req.session of the routes.js

I think that jest don't know express session and thats why the test never finish

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your API call, I recommend you to mock your API response

Comment: i will try that and tell you about the result

Comment: i did this and it works the API Call is OK but impossible to test the route